# How would you combine results from 2 separate queries?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench, common-table-expression

I have an table with 3 columns: ID, Name, and Salary.

There are 2 cases. 1 where the salary column is missing all 0s and other with the original salary. The question is:: What would be the difference between the average salaries between the 2? I got the Average salary with and without 0s but don't understand how I can find the difference?

```
Select AVG(Salary) AS Salary_with0
from Employees
where Salary regexp '[0]'

UNION ALL

select AVG(Salary) AS Salary_without0
from Employees
where Salary NOT regexp '[0]'
```

I know there are easier methods of doing this using replace but I really want to understand this.

Thanks

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  Why would you be using `regexp` a numeric column?

Comment: What do you mean by `missing all 0s`?

Comment: What does *missing all 0s* mean? The column is null? The column is missing leading 0s? The column is blank? What is the type of the column?

Answer (score 0):

It is easy enough to answer your question:

```
Select AVG(case when Salary regexp '[0]' then Salary end) AS Salary_with0,
       AVG(case when Salary not regexp '[0]' then Salary end) AS Salary_with0,       
from Employees;
```

You can subtract the values to get the difference.

The *utility* of this is another matter.  Normally, one doesn't use regular expressions on numbers.  And "missing zeros" seems rather strange as a description for whatever is happening.